# Are those Keras and PyTorch snippets equivalent?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I am wondering if I succeeded in translating the following definition in PyTorch to Keras?

In PyTorch, the following multi-layer perceptron was defined:

```
from torch import nn
hidden = 128
def mlp(size_in, size_out, act=nn.ReLU):
    return nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(size_in, hidden),
        act(),
        nn.Linear(hidden, hidden),
        act(),
        nn.Linear(hidden, hidden),
        act(),
        nn.Linear(hidden, size_out),
    )
```

My translation is

```
from tensorflow import keras

from keras import layers

hidden = 128

def mlp(size_in, size_out, act=keras.layers.ReLU):
    return keras.Sequential(
        [
            layers.Dense(hidden, activation=None, name="layer1", input_shape=(size_in, 1)),
            act(),
            layers.Dense(hidden, activation=None, name="layer2", input_shape=(hidden, 1)),
            act(),
            layers.Dense(hidden, activation=None, name="layer3", input_shape=(hidden, 1)),
            act(),
            layers.Dense(size_out, activation=None, name="layer4", input_shape=(hidden, 1))
        ])
```

I am particularly confused about the input/output arguments, because that seems to be where tensorflow and PyTorch differ.

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense):

> When a popular kwarg input_shape is passed, then keras will create an
> input layer to insert before the current layer. This can be treated
> equivalent to explicitly defining an InputLayer.

So, did I get it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Keras, you can provide an `input_shape` for the first layer or alternatively use the [`tf.keras.layers.Input`](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/input/) layer. If you do not provide either of these details, the model gets built the first time you call `fit`, `eval`, or `predict`, or the first time you call the model on some input data. So the input shape will actually be inferred if you do not provide it. See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential) for more details. PyTorch generally infers the input shape at runtime.

```
def keras_mlp(size_in, size_out, act=layers.ReLU):
    return keras.Sequential([layers.Input(shape=(size_in,)),
                             layers.Dense(hidden, name='layer1'),
                             act(),
                             layers.Dense(hidden, name='layer2'),
                             act(),
                             layers.Dense(hidden, name='layer3'),
                             act(),
                             layers.Dense(size_out, name='layer4')])

def pytorch_mlp(size_in, size_out, act=nn.ReLU):
    return nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(size_in, hidden),
                         act(),
                         nn.Linear(hidden, hidden),
                         act(),
                         nn.Linear(hidden, hidden),
                         act(),
                         nn.Linear(hidden, size_out))
```

You can compare their summary.

- For Keras:

  ```
  >>> keras_mlp(10, 5).summary()
  Model: "sequential_2"
  _________________________________________________________________
   Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
  =================================================================
   layer1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               1408      

   re_lu_6 (ReLU)              (None, 128)               0         

   layer2 (Dense)              (None, 128)               16512     

   re_lu_7 (ReLU)              (None, 128)               0         

   layer3 (Dense)              (None, 128)               16512     

   re_lu_8 (ReLU)              (None, 128)               0         

   layer4 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 645       

  =================================================================
  Total params: 35,077
  Trainable params: 35,077
  Non-trainable params: 0
  _________________________________________________________________
  ```
- For PyTorch:

  ```
  >>> summary(pytorch_mlp(10, 5), (1,10))
  ============================================================================
  Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Output Shape              Param #
  ============================================================================
  Sequential                               [1, 5]                    --
  ├─Linear: 1-1                            [1, 128]                  1,408
  ├─ReLU: 1-2                              [1, 128]                  --
  ├─Linear: 1-3                            [1, 128]                  16,512
  ├─ReLU: 1-4                              [1, 128]                  --
  ├─Linear: 1-5                            [1, 128]                  16,512
  ├─ReLU: 1-6                              [1, 128]                  --
  ├─Linear: 1-7                            [1, 5]                    645
  ============================================================================
  Total params: 35,077
  Trainable params: 35,077
  Non-trainable params: 0
  Total mult-adds (M): 0.04
  ============================================================================
  Input size (MB): 0.00
  Forward/backward pass size (MB): 0.00
  Params size (MB): 0.14
  Estimated Total Size (MB): 0.14
  ============================================================================
  ```